# Magento - Collection with Filter displaying incorrect results

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to get SKU counts outside of Magento for reporting reasons. The first string for the total number of SKUs shows the correct count (being over 600,000). The second string for the total number of SKUs with price shows only 2000, and only another 2000 or so when I set it to 'null' rather than notnull.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default'); // Default or your store view name.

// Total Number of SKUs
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getsize();
var_dump($products);

// Total Number of SKUs with Price
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToFilter('price', 'notnull')->getsize();
var_dump($products);
```

Originally I thought it could be the indexes so I processed the indexes and it's still showing the incorrect counts. I'm just wondering if the syntax I have for doing this is wrong considering I'm using Magento 1.7...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to output the sku list in the second collection and check the common points of these products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work fine: (just fixed condition) ;-)

```
// Total Number of SKUs with Price
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        //->addMinimalPrice()
        //->addFinalPrice()
        //->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('notnull'=>true))
        ->getSize()
;

var_dump($products);
```

May be helpful:

> array("eq" => 'ZH12b5') - WHERE (sku = 'ZH12b5')
>
> array("neq" => 'ZH12b5') - WHERE (sku <> 'ZH12b5')
>
> array("like" => 'ZH12b5') - WHERE (sku LIKE 'ZH12b5')
>
> array("nlike" => 'ZH') - WHERE (sku NOT LIKE 'ZH')
>
> array("is" => 'zh') - WHERE (sku IS 'zh')
>
> array("in" => array('zh', 'pl')) - WHERE (sku IN ('zh', 'pl'))
>
> array("nin" => array('zh', 'pl')) - WHERE (sku NOT IN ('zh', 'pl'))
>
> array("notnull" => true ) - WHERE (sku IS NOT NULL)
>
> array("null" => true) - WHERE (sku IS  NULL)
>
> array("gt" => 5) - HERE (sku > 5)
>
> array("lt" => 10) - WHERE (sku < 10 )
>
> array("gteq" => 10) - WHERE (sku >= 5)
>
> array("lteq" => 22) - WHERE (sku =< 5)
>
> array("finset" => array('test')) - WHERE (find_in_set('test', sku))
>
> array('from' => 2, 'to' => 30) - WHERE (sku >= '2' AND sku <= '30')